# apply css while binding in the JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to give some css value to my one of the element from the below code.

```
_strInnerHtml += "<h3>"+ p_strDay + "-" + dictCalendarmonth[p_strMonth] + "-" + p_strYear + "</h3>" + "<h4>" + value.cati_tithi_name + "</h4>";
```

I want to show the `<h3>` & `h4` in the same line. How can I put the css there?

```
 _strInnerHtml += "<h3 style = "color:blue">"+ p_strDay + "-" + dictCalendarmonth[p_strMonth] + "-" + p_strYear + "</h3>" + "<h4>" + value.cati_tithi_name + "</h4>";
```

This way its not working..

Comment: why not create a specific css class and just style it on the css and give the class to the element?

Comment: What does "binding" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Either escape double quotes  or put single quote for css color property.
But the best solution will be adding specific CSS class

Answer (score 0):

Don't process the elements as String. Use `document.createElement()` to create new element (any HTML DOM element). Then you can set style easily. Like:

```
var h3= document.createElement('h3');
h3.style.property= 'value';
```

See more:

1. [HTML DOM createElement()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)
2. [Changing CSS using JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

And create a parent `div` to keep `h3` and `h4` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you should add CSS class like

```
.heading{
    //css property
}
```

and add into JavaScript

```
_strInnerHtml += "<h3 class = 'heading'>"+ p_strDay + "-" + dictCalendarmonth[p_strMonth] + "-" + p_strYear + "</h3>" + "<h4>" + value.cati_tithi_name + "</h4>";
```

if you want to show both `h3` and `h4` in a same line 
add this CSS class in both

```
.half{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```